# HTML5 SVG D3.js Часы

Tags: svg, d3.js

Здравствуйте. 
Пример часов [Simple D3 clock](http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/6475678), модифицирую под себя. 
Надо чтобы цифры были повёрнуты параллельно соответствующим им рискам часов и минут. Как это сделать? 
Смотрел разные примеры и пытался что-то, не получилось. 
Если подскажете как это сделать, будет здорово. 
Благодарю.

Решение нашлось, благодарю transform. 
В итоге получилось так:

```js
var radians = 0.0174532925, 
 clockRadius = 200,
 margin = 50,
 width = (clockRadius+margin)*2,
    height = (clockRadius+margin)*2,
    hourHandLength = 2*clockRadius/3,
    minuteHandLength = clockRadius,
    secondHandLength = clockRadius-12,
    secondHandBalance = 30,
    secondTickStart = clockRadius;
    secondTickLength = -10,
    hourTickStart = clockRadius,
    hourTickLength = -18,
    secondLabelRadius = clockRadius + 6,
    secondLabelYOffset = 0,
    hourLabelRadius = clockRadius - 40,
    hourLabelYOffset = 7;


var hourScale = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([0,330])
 .domain([0,11]);

var minuteScale = secondScale = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([0,354])
 .domain([0,59]);

var handData = [
 {
  type:'hour',
  value:0,
  length:-hourHandLength,
  scale:hourScale
 },
 {
  type:'minute',
  value:0,
  length:-minuteHandLength,
  scale:minuteScale
 },
 {
  type:'second',
  value:0,
  length:-secondHandLength,
  scale:secondScale,
  balance:secondHandBalance
 }
];

function drawClock(){ //create all the clock elements
 updateData(); //draw them in the correct starting position
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);

 var face = svg.append('g')
  .attr('id','clock-face')
  .attr('transform','translate(' + (clockRadius + margin) + ',' + (clockRadius + margin) + ')');

 //add marks for seconds
 face.selectAll('.second-tick')
  .data(d3.range(0,60)).enter()
   .append('line')
   .attr('class', 'second-tick')
   .attr('x1',0)
   .attr('x2',0)
   .attr('y1',secondTickStart)
   .attr('y2',secondTickStart + secondTickLength)
   .attr('transform',function(d){
    return 'rotate(' + secondScale(d) + ')';
   });
 //and labels

 face.selectAll('.second-label')
  .data(d3.range(1,61,1))
   .enter()
   .append('text')
   .attr('class', 'second-label')
   .attr('text-anchor','middle')
   .attr('x',function(d){
    return secondLabelRadius*Math.sin(secondScale(d)*radians);
   })
   .attr('y',function(d){
    return -secondLabelRadius*Math.cos(secondScale(d)*radians) + secondLabelYOffset;
   })

      .attr('transform',function(d){
         var that = d3.select(this),
             x = that.attr("x"),
             y = that.attr("y"),
             angle = d/5 * 30;
         return "rotate("+angle+","+x+","+y+") ";                 
      })
      .text(function(d){
              return d;
            });

      


 //... and hours
 face.selectAll('.hour-tick')
  .data(d3.range(0,12)).enter()
   .append('line')
   .attr('class', 'hour-tick')
   .attr('x1',0)
   .attr('x2',0)
   .attr('y1',hourTickStart)
   .attr('y2',hourTickStart + hourTickLength)
   .attr('transform',function(d){
    return 'rotate(' + hourScale(d) + ')';
   });

 face.selectAll('.hour-label')
  .data(d3.range(3,13,3))
   .enter()
   .append('text')
   .attr('class', 'hour-label')
   .attr('text-anchor','middle')
   .attr('x',function(d){
    return hourLabelRadius*Math.sin(hourScale(d)*radians);
   })
   .attr('y',function(d){
    return -hourLabelRadius*Math.cos(hourScale(d)*radians) + hourLabelYOffset;
   })
   .text(function(d){
    return d;
   });


 var hands = face.append('g').attr('id','clock-hands');

 face.append('g').attr('id','face-overlay')
  .append('circle').attr('class','hands-cover')
   .attr('x',0)
   .attr('y',0)
   .attr('r',clockRadius/20);

 hands.selectAll('line')
  .data(handData)
   .enter()
   .append('line')
   .attr('class', function(d){
    return d.type + '-hand';
   })
   .attr('x1',0)
   .attr('y1',function(d){
    return d.balance ? d.balance : 0;
   })
   .attr('x2',0)
   .attr('y2',function(d){
    return d.length;
   })
   .attr('transform',function(d){
    return 'rotate('+ d.scale(d.value) +')';
   });
}

function moveHands(){
 d3.select('#clock-hands').selectAll('line')
 .data(handData)
  .transition()
  .attr('transform',function(d){
   return 'rotate('+ d.scale(d.value) +')';
  });
}

function updateData(){
 var t = new Date();
 handData[0].value = (t.getHours() % 12) + t.getMinutes()/60 ;
 handData[1].value = t.getMinutes();
 handData[2].value = t.getSeconds();
}

drawClock();

setInterval(function(){
 updateData();
 moveHands();
}, 1000);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

svg{
 stroke: #000;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
}

#rim {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.second-hand{
 stroke-width:3;
}

.minute-hand{
 stroke-width:8;
 stroke-linecap:round;
}

.hour-hand{
 stroke-width:12;
 stroke-linecap:round;
}

.hands-cover{
 stroke-width:3;
 fill:#fff;
}

.second-tick{
 stroke-width:3;
 fill:#000; 
}

.hour-tick{
 stroke-width:8; //same as the miute hand
}

.second-label{
 font-size: 12px;
}

.hour-label{
 font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У самой библиотеки D3 нет такой возможности, это сказано на главной странице.

> Transformation, not Representation
>
> D3 does not introduce a new visual representation. Unlike Processing,
>   Raphaël, or Protovis, D3’s vocabulary of graphical marks comes
>   directly from web standards: HTML, SVG, and CSS. For example, you can
>   create SVG elements using D3 and style them with external stylesheets.
>   You can use composite filter effects, dashed strokes and clipping. If
>   browser vendors introduce new features tomorrow, you’ll be able to use
>   them immediately—no toolkit update required. And, if you decide in the
>   future to use a toolkit other than D3, you can take your knowledge of
>   standards with you!
>
> Best of all, D3 is easy to debug using the browser’s built-in element
>   inspector: the nodes that you manipulate with D3 are exactly those
>   that the browser understands natively.

Поэтому обходится Вам придется простым SVG аттрибутом [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)

```js
d3.select("#example").attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(90)"; })
d3.select("#example2").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(10,10) rotate(45)"; })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <text id="example">text text text</text>
  <text id="example2">text text text</text>
</svg>
```

Решение взято [по этому примеру](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4739610f6d96aaad2fb1e78a72b385ab)

---

**UPD**

В примере данных часов уже есть изменение координат `x` и `y`, а так же глобальный `translate` у элемента выше `<g id="clock-face" transform="translate(250,250)">`. То есть у Вас вращение происходит относительно точки `{250,250}` или же центр часов другими словами, поэтому текст вращается как бы вокруг них. Данные факторы надо учитывать, в частности изменить точку для вращения. Для этого надо использовать или матричные преобразования или воспользоваться расширенной формой `rotate(deg, x, y)`, где `x` и `y` задают точку вращения.

Итоговые изменения будут выглядеть так:

```
 .attr('transform',function(d){
     var that = d3.select(this),
         x = that.attr("x"),
         y = that.attr("y"),
         angle = d/5 * 30;
     return  "rotate("+angle+","+x+","+y+") ";                 
  })
```

Итоговый пример:

```js
var radians = 0.0174532925, 
 clockRadius = 200,
 margin = 50,
 width = (clockRadius+margin)*2,
    height = (clockRadius+margin)*2,
    hourHandLength = 2*clockRadius/3,
    minuteHandLength = clockRadius,
    secondHandLength = clockRadius-12,
    secondHandBalance = 30,
    secondTickStart = clockRadius;
    secondTickLength = -10,
    hourTickStart = clockRadius,
    hourTickLength = -18
    secondLabelRadius = clockRadius + 16;
    secondLabelYOffset = 5
    hourLabelRadius = clockRadius - 40
    hourLabelYOffset = 7;


var hourScale = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([0,330])
 .domain([0,11]);

var minuteScale = secondScale = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([0,354])
 .domain([0,59]);

var handData = [
 {
  type:'hour',
  value:0,
  length:-hourHandLength,
  scale:hourScale
 },
 {
  type:'minute',
  value:0,
  length:-minuteHandLength,
  scale:minuteScale
 },
 {
  type:'second',
  value:0,
  length:-secondHandLength,
  scale:secondScale,
  balance:secondHandBalance
 }
];

function drawClock(){ //create all the clock elements
 updateData(); //draw them in the correct starting position
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);

 var face = svg.append('g')
  .attr('id','clock-face')
  .attr('transform','translate(' + (clockRadius + margin) + ',' + (clockRadius + margin) + ')');

 //add marks for seconds
 face.selectAll('.second-tick')
  .data(d3.range(0,60)).enter()
   .append('line')
   .attr('class', 'second-tick')
   .attr('x1',0)
   .attr('x2',0)
   .attr('y1',secondTickStart)
   .attr('y2',secondTickStart + secondTickLength)
   .attr('transform',function(d){
    return 'rotate(' + secondScale(d) + ')';
   });
 //and labels

 face.selectAll('.second-label')
  .data(d3.range(5,61,5))
   .enter()
   .append('text')
   .attr('class', 'second-label')
   .attr('text-anchor','middle')
   .attr('x',function(d){
    return secondLabelRadius*Math.sin(secondScale(d)*radians);
   })
   .attr('y',function(d){
    return -secondLabelRadius*Math.cos(secondScale(d)*radians) + secondLabelYOffset;
   })
      .attr('transform',function(d){
         var that = d3.select(this),
             x = that.attr("x"),
             y = that.attr("y"),
             angle = d/5 * 30;
         return "rotate("+angle+","+x+","+y+") ";                 
      })
   .text(function(d){
    return d;
   }); 
      


 //... and hours
 face.selectAll('.hour-tick')
  .data(d3.range(0,12)).enter()
   .append('line')
   .attr('class', 'hour-tick')
   .attr('x1',0)
   .attr('x2',0)
   .attr('y1',hourTickStart)
   .attr('y2',hourTickStart + hourTickLength)
   .attr('transform',function(d){
    return 'rotate(' + hourScale(d) + ')';
   });

 face.selectAll('.hour-label')
  .data(d3.range(3,13,3))
   .enter()
   .append('text')
   .attr('class', 'hour-label')
   .attr('text-anchor','middle')
   .attr('x',function(d){
    return hourLabelRadius*Math.sin(hourScale(d)*radians);
   })
   .attr('y',function(d){
    return -hourLabelRadius*Math.cos(hourScale(d)*radians) + hourLabelYOffset;
   })
   .text(function(d){
    return d;
   });


 var hands = face.append('g').attr('id','clock-hands');

 face.append('g').attr('id','face-overlay')
  .append('circle').attr('class','hands-cover')
   .attr('x',0)
   .attr('y',0)
   .attr('r',clockRadius/20);

 hands.selectAll('line')
  .data(handData)
   .enter()
   .append('line')
   .attr('class', function(d){
    return d.type + '-hand';
   })
   .attr('x1',0)
   .attr('y1',function(d){
    return d.balance ? d.balance : 0;
   })
   .attr('x2',0)
   .attr('y2',function(d){
    return d.length;
   })
   .attr('transform',function(d){
    return 'rotate('+ d.scale(d.value) +')';
   });
}

function moveHands(){
 d3.select('#clock-hands').selectAll('line')
 .data(handData)
  .transition()
  .attr('transform',function(d){
   return 'rotate('+ d.scale(d.value) +')';
  });
}

function updateData(){
 var t = new Date();
 handData[0].value = (t.getHours() % 12) + t.getMinutes()/60 ;
 handData[1].value = t.getMinutes();
 handData[2].value = t.getSeconds();
}

drawClock();

setInterval(function(){
 updateData();
 moveHands();
}, 1000);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

svg{
 stroke: #000;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
}

#rim {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.second-hand{
 stroke-width:3;
}

.minute-hand{
 stroke-width:8;
 stroke-linecap:round;
}

.hour-hand{
 stroke-width:12;
 stroke-linecap:round;
}

.hands-cover{
 stroke-width:3;
 fill:#fff;
}

.second-tick{
 stroke-width:3;
 fill:#000; 
}

.hour-tick{
 stroke-width:8; //same as the miute hand
}

.second-label{
 font-size: 12px;
}

.hour-label{
 font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы правы, наверное, но когда вставляю    `.attr('transform',function(d){
    return 'rotate(' + minuteScale(d) +  ')';
   });` цифры поворачиваются , но непонятно как-то, не как надо. Из этого делаю вывод что вращать умеет, но я не так делаю что-то .

Comment: @Илья, вращает он вокруг точки 0,0. Что бы изменить эту точку, надо использовать `translate({x}, {y})` как в примере. Добиться нужного вращения можно комбинирую эти два параметра или высчитывая их по более сложным формулам.

Comment: Что мог перепробовал. Специально взял известный пример часов, на который много ссылок и о котором есть отзывы хорошие, чтобы исключить неоднозначность. В других примерах, где svg без библиотек,  всё хорошо вращается.  А как сделать в этом примере? В чистом svg нужно будет каждую риску прописывать , что долго. Хотя, если не найдётся решение, возможно , так и поступлю.  transform предложил вариант, возможно, это хорошее решение. Специалист сразу видит что и как, такой как я , может долго и безуспешно тыкаться.

Comment: @Илья Приведите свой вариант решения, тогда будет проще помочь найти ошибку или посоветовать куда двигаться.

Comment: @Alexandr Сделал пример в  [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/32gnh53g/1/) .  При добавлении строк 90-92 цифры минут вращаются и сбивается их расположение. Без этих строй, как в  исходном примере, цифры располагаются на своих местах вертикально. Я не знаю как адаптировать под данный пример решение, которое показал transform.

Comment: Точнее, строки 89-91

Comment: @Илья, я обновил ответ под пример этих конкретных часов.

Comment: @Alex Krass , благодарю. Цифры поворачиваются, но располагаются со смещением относительно рисок и центр круга, по которому располагаются цифры смещён вниз относительно центра часов. Для наглядности изменил строку 14: 'secondLabelRadius = clockRadius + 6;' , строку 75:'.data(d3.range(1,61,1))' . [Вот код на jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/32gnh53g/6/)

Comment: Разобрался. Всё отлично работает. Спасибо.